# Does Oracle jdbc driver support SOCKS5 proxy?

Tags: oracle10g, ojdbc

I am trying to figure out if Oracle JDBC driver supports SOCKS proxy or not. I am not finding any documentation related to this. Please let know if you are aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the Oracle JDBC driver doesn't support SOCKS5 proxy. In the soon to be release 18.1 version of the thin driver there will be support for HTTPS proxy and websocket.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only when disabling java NIO for jdbc by passing `-Doracle.jdbc.javaNetNio=false` to jvm or setting the property programmatically.

You can then use the standard `socksproxyHost` and `socksproxyPort` properties to configure the proxy.